# Two way binding with controller in directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Im developing a directive, where when the user will click UPDATE, a field for EmployeeId will show up, and that employeeId field on the directive should be bound directly to the controller when changes. If i isolate the scope it doesn't change the controller employeeId, if i dont, than all directives gets toggled.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/aq06WnfniN51iR7ZtFLc?p=preview

code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.employeeId = 'Josh'
    $scope.employeePin = '1234'

    $scope.updateFields = function() {
        alert(1);
    }
});

app.directive('crudEmp', function($parse) {
    var html =  '<div class="form-inline">\
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"\
                        placeholder="Employe ID"\
                        ng-model="employeeId"\
                        required\
                        ng-show="isEditing"/>\
                    <input type="password" class="form-control"\
                        placeholder="Employe PIN"\
                        ng-model="employeePin"\
                        ng-show="user.AdminSecurity && isEditing"\
                        ng-required="user.AdminSecurity"\
                        disabled/>\
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-right noPadding pt10 operationButtons" id="opBtn">\
                        <div class="col-md-12 noPadding" ng-hide="isEditing">\
                            <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="toggleEditing()">Edit</button>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-right noPadding" ng-hide="!isEditing">\
                            <button class="btn btn-success mr80 updateBtn" ng-click="ctrl.onClick(); toggleEditing()" ng-disabled="ctrl.valid">Update</button>\
                            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="toggleEditing()">Cancel</button>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: html,
        replace: true,
        bindToController: {
            employeeId: '=',
            employeePin: '=',
            valid: '=',
            onClick: '&',
        },
//      scope: true,   // When i make the scope true, it doesnt change the EmployeeId defined in the controller
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            scope.onClick = attr.onClick;

            scope.toggleEditing = function() {
                scope.isEditing = !scope.isEditing;
                if(scope.isEditing){
                    element.closest('form').find(':input:not(.operationButtons button)').attr('disabled', false);
                    var getAllInputs = element.closest('form').find(':input').filter(':visible:enabled');
                    if(getAllInputs[0]){
                        getAllInputs[0].focus();
                    }
                }else{
                    element.closest('form').find(':input:not(.operationButtons button)').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            };
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: function($scope) {
            var ctrl = this;

            ctrl.onClick = function() {
                $scope.$eval($scope.onClick);
            };
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: Did you create to create a Service/Factory to share data between controller and directive?

Comment: No i have not, i pass them in the attributes of the directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you currently it would be solved by changing:

```
    ...
            restrict: 'E',
            template: html,
            replace: true,
            bindToController: {
                employeeId: '=',
                employeePin: '=',
                valid: '=',
                onClick: '&',
            },
    //      scope: true,   // When i make the scope true, it doesnt change
```

To:

```
...
        restrict: 'E',
        template: html,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            employeeId: '=',
            employeePin: '=',
            valid: '=',
            onClick: '&',
        },
    ...
```

You can verify the behaviour in my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Xia8BhlfFJ6mqgLjaoOp?p=preview

Comment: Thats right, but in your behavior i cant trigger the onClick passed function from controller.
I want that when the customer click on the SAVE button, to trigger a function from the controller

Comment: This works, there is a problem cause i assigned a variable to onClick. Ty

Comment: Btw. Is there a way to bind the employeeId and employeePin controller variable to directive without passing them at the directives attribute like:
employee-id and employee-pin ?

Comment: Im not 100% never really worked alot with it,. If you want the same directive with the same scope but dont want to use isolated scope you properly need alot of self wiring to my knowledge.

You could use the iElm id to be an alias identifier so the different values would be saved in scope.directiveHashMap[element.id].employeeId 
This way you could make your own mapingOfTheValues.


If you dont care about isolated scope and just need one directive pr page. Then this: https://plnkr.co/edit/drRRlavV2fEgQDc4Ivaq?p=preview

I've never done the first just a idea without research.